# Get windows title using php doesn't work on browser call

Tags: php, windows, winapi, visual-c++, browser

My problem is I need to fetch FOOBAR2000's title because that including information of playing file, so I create a execute file via Win32 API(`GetWindowText()`, `EnumWindows()`) and it's working good.

```
TCHAR SearchText[MAX_LOADSTRING] = _T("foobar2000");

BOOL CALLBACK WorkerProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_TITLESTRING];

    GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, MAX_TITLESTRING);
    if(_tcsstr(buffer, SearchText))
    {
        // find it output something
    }

    return TRUE;
}

EnumWindows(WorkerProc, NULL);
```

Output would look like "**album artis title .... [foobar2000 v1.1.5]**"

I created a php file like test.php, and use `exec()` to execute it.

```
exec("foobar.exe");
```

then in console(cmd) I use command to execute it

```
php test.php
```

It's working good too, same output like before.

Now I use browser(firefox) to call this php file(test.php), strange things happened.
The output only **foobar2000 v1.1.5**, others information gone ...

I think maybe is `exec()` problem? priority or some limitation, so I use C# to create a COM Object and register it, and rewrite php code

```
$mydll = new COM("FOOBAR_COMObject.FOOBAR_Class");
echo $mydll->GetFooBarTitle();
```

still same result, command line OK, but browser Fail.

My question is

1. Why have 2 different output between command line and browser. I can't figure it out.
2. How can I get correct output via browser.
3. or there is a easy way to fetch FOOBAR2000's title?

Does anyone have experience on this problem?

== 2012/11/28 edited ==

follow Enno's opinion, I modify http_control plug-in to add filename info, original json info is "track title".

modify as following

state.cpp line 380 add 1 line

```
+pb_helper1 = pfc::string_filename(pb_item_ptr->get_path());
 pb_helper1x = xml_friendly_string(pb_helper1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ 1: when firefox opens the php and it gets executed, it the context depends on the user which runs the php-container (apache), this is quite different from the commandline call which gets executed in your context

@ 2 and 3: there seems to be more than one way for getting the title: use the foobar-sdk and create a module which simply reads the current title per api, then write your result in an static-html-document inside your http-root-folder OR use the http-client inside the sdk, with it, you do not need a wabserver, even better use a already implemented module: for instance foo_upnp or foo-httpcontrol

Good luck!

Comment: Using foobar sdk is my final choice...I hope to solve this problem not use foobar sdk because I don't know foobar develop environment. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver runs as a service, in windows you need to enable "allow desktop interaction" for the service. Your php script runs as a child of the webserver process when requested via browser.

Comment: I try to system manage tools / service / Apache2.2 and enable "allow desktop interaction", but output is empty